# Change colors of each item in jQuery fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using [Fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) for a planning of each employee. I want a different color for each item corresponding to a different employee.

I added in a jQuery file the following lines:

```
var couleur = $('span.color').text();
$('span.color').hide();

var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();

var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    eventClick: updateEvent,
    eventColor:couleur,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,
    select: selectDate,
    editable: true,

    events: "JsonResponse.ashx",
    eventDrop: eventDropped,
    eventResize: eventResized,
    eventRender: function (event, element) {
        //alert(event.title);

        element.qtip({
            content: event.description,
            position: { corner: { tooltip: 'bottomLeft', target: 'topleft'} },
            style: {
                border: {
                    width: 0,
                    radius: 3,
                    color: '#2779AA'

                },
                padding: 10,
                textAlign: 'left',
                tip: true, // Give it a speech bubble tip with automatic corner detection
                name: 'cream',
                width: 400,
                heigth: 600    // Style it according to the preset 'cream' style
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And in the page that contains the calendar:

```
<div id="calendar" runat="server">
    <span id="span1" class="color" runat="server">red</span>
</div>
```

And in the back-end code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //CalendarEvent cevent;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source=PC;Initial Catalog=base;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=hhh");
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select couleur_planning from cadres where prénom='maher'", con2);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    // con2.Open()
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    span1.InnerText ="";

    span1.InnerText = dt.Rows[0]["couleur_planning"].ToString();
}
```

And it does not work. It colors all event colors by last color. [I saw a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5668248/how-i-change-events-background-color-with-different-colors-in-fullcalendar) and that's exactly what I want but I need to do it programmatically (I'm using the last version of *fullcalendar*).

Data are extracted from that class:

```
public static List<CalendarEvent> getEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    //  string listcheck = HttpContext.Current.Session["listcheck"].ToString();
    List<CalendarEvent> events = new List<CalendarEvent>();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    string sql;
    sql = "select D.date_deb as deb,D.date_fin as fin ,M.code as code,M.Objet as ob,M.type_mission as t,M.ville," +
"  M.Etat_mission,prénom,'Mission' AS type,S.nom  from Mission_date D  inner join missions M on " +
   " M.code=D.code_mission inner join mission_cadre C on D.code_mission=C.code_mission inner join cadres on cadres.code=C.code_cadre" +
    " join sociétés S on S.code=M.code_client " +
 "   where  ((D.Date_deb>='" + start + "' and D.Date_deb<='" + end + "')  OR (D.Date_fin>='" + start + "' and D.Date_fin<='" + end + "')) and " +
      " C.code_cadre In (select code from cadres)   union select tache_date.date_deb,tache_date.date_fin ,taches.code,Objet,type_tache,'',Etat_tache,prénom,'Tache' AS type,''  from tache_date " +
    "inner join taches on taches.code=tache_date.code_tache inner join tache_cadre C on tache_date.code_tache=C.code_tache inner join cadres on cadres.code=C.code_cadre where " +
     "((tache_date.Date_deb>='" + start + "' and tache_date.Date_deb<='" + end + "')  OR (tache_date.Date_fin>='" + start + "' and tache_date.Date_fin<='" + end + "')) and  C.code_cadre In (select code from cadres) " +
"union select Réunions.DateRéunion + Réunions.HeureDébut,Réunions.DateRéunion + Réunions.HeureFin ,Réunions.code,Réunions.Objet,''," +
 " '','',prénom,'Réunion' AS type,'' from Réunions  inner join réunion_cadre on .."

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
          using (con)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {

            CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent();
            // cevent.id = (Int32 )reader["code"];
            cevent.title = (string)reader[8] + ":" + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[7]) + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[9]) + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[6]) + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[4]) + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[3]) + "|" + SearchForChar((string)reader[5]) + "|";
            cevent.description = (string)reader[8] + ":" + "|" + (string)reader[7] + "|" + (string)reader[9] + "|" + (string)reader[6] + "|" + (string)reader[4] + "|" + (string)reader[3] + "|" + (string)reader[5] + "|";
            cevent.start = (DateTime)reader["deb"];
            cevent.end = (DateTime)reader["fin"];
            cevent.ApplyColor(Color.Aqua);
            events.Add(cevent);

        }
    }
    return events;
     }
```

And the JSON file :

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

    DateTime start = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
    DateTime end = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);

    start = start.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["start"]));
    end = end.AddSeconds(double.Parse(context.Request.QueryString["end"]));


    String result = String.Empty;

    result += "[";

    List<int> idList = new List<int>();
    foreach (CalendarEvent cevent in EventDAO.getEvents(start, end))
    {
        result += convertCalendarEventIntoString(cevent);
        idList.Add(cevent.id);
    }

    if (result.EndsWith(","))
    {
        result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
    }

    result += "]";
    //store list of event ids in Session, so that it can be accessed in web methods
    context.Session["idList"] = idList;

    context.Response.Write(result);
}

private String convertCalendarEventIntoString(CalendarEvent cevent)
{
    String allDay = "true";
    if (ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString().Equals(ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString()))
    {

        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (cevent.start.Hour == 0 && cevent.start.Minute == 0 && cevent.start.Second == 0
            && cevent.end.Hour == 0 && cevent.end.Minute == 0 && cevent.end.Second == 0)
        {
            allDay = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            allDay = "false";
        }
    }
    return    "{" +
              "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
              "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
              "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
              "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
              "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
              "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +
              "},";
}


public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{


    long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;

}
}
```

Comment: Why can't you set `backgroundColor` in your server side for each of the events you are returning to the calendar? Can you post the output of your server-side code - wanted to see how your events array is formed? Also, can you post how you are initializing the FullCalendar?

Comment: @ganeshk:thx for the answer.heres the calendar [link]https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=3fcefcc97f3a15b6#cid=3FCEFCC97F3A15B6&id=3FCEFCC97F3A15B6%21120

Comment: And what I want is color the calendar by employee(Maher,Bechir,...) the calendar is initialized in JScript file : var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,  #calendar is the div in the aspx page

Comment: Can you post the output of your server-side code - I need to see how your events array is formed? Also, please post your JS code. You can edit your question to do so. I'll be able to advise you better that way.

Comment: @ganeshk hi:thx for your implication with my problem.I edited my question as you suggested.hope its clear.If its not I can upload my project on skydrive.Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `backgroundColor` in your `ProcessRequest` or `convertCalendarEventIntoString` functions. Essentially, your event string should look something like this:

```
return    "{" +
              "id: '" + cevent.id + "'," +
              "title: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.title) + "'," +
              "start:  " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.start).ToString() + "," +
              "end: " + ConvertToTimestamp(cevent.end).ToString() + "," +
              "allDay:" + allDay + "," +
              "description: '" + HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(cevent.description) + "'" +
              "backgroundColor:" + backgroundColor + "," +
              "},";
```

Let me know how it goes..